# Combine multiple records into one based on a condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to combine each product_code's (comma-separated) in a single entry/record if all other values in multiple records are the same except the product_code

The dataset looks like below-

```
category_id subcat_id  product_code customer_id  quantity   value
   123        456        AB            111          2         1
   123        456        CD            111          2         1
   123        789        AB            111          2         2
   123        789        CD            111          2         2
```

The result should look like-

```
category_id subcat_id  product_code   customer_id    quantity   value
   123        456        AB,CD             111          2         1
   123        789        AB,CD             111          2         2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string_agg()`;

```
select category_id, subcat_id, customer_id, quantity, value,
       string_agg(product_code, ',')
from t
group by category_id, subcat_id, customer_id, quantity, value;
```

That said, I recommend arrays instead of strings for storing such values.